# Is it wrong to use the word "codes" in a programming context?

Tags: grammatical-number, programming, uncountable-nouns

Is it wrong to use the word "codes" in programming context?

> I shall use these codes.

Comment: "Gimme the codez" has become kind of a meme in the programming world, due to the large amount of wannabe (but not *wannalearn*) people who invade programming forums saying "Plz gimme the codez for xxxx"... definitely NOT correct English.

Comment: the above comment obviously should read "programmer wannabe"...

Comment: This question is ambiguous.  In this context, does 'code' refer to programming language *source code*, a standard character set like *ASCII code*, a proprietary security system *password code*, command line *switch code*, or some other valid use of the word 'code' as it pertains to software use and development?

Comment: "I shall use these *scripts*" is more likely what a programmer would say.

Comment: Whoa! So much talk without even asking the OP what he is referring to by *codes*? He only said 'in programming context', not 'program' or 'program segment'. Peeps!

Comment: My new favorite question to cross link to from SO, +1!

Comment: @oosterwal The question is *technically* ambiguous but I think anyone involved in programming would know what the question means, we see it often in badly-written blog posts (particularly on Medium!), and any writing about any other kind of "codes" such as you have given examples of would be explicitly stated as (e.g. ASCII) codepages etc. In fact I have never heard of a "command line switch code" (try Googling it) - it's just a switch, and a "password code" means nothing to me - do you mean an alarm code? Either way, these other uses have extra, qualifying words, rather than just "code".

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion here between the use of "code" to mean software versus "code" in the sense of "codes and cyphers".  "Codes" used to mean something like, "If I send you a telegram containing the word 'Tuesday', please come and retrieve me."  Secret codes were found in code-books.  They're very secure, unlike HTML return codes.  I suspect in the early days someone looked at a line of software such as " L R4,OFFSET " and decided it must be a secret code...  There's a very large company that sells a flight simulator that claims to include "aircrafts".  O, tempora! O, mores!

Answer (score 142, accepted):

As a programmer, I cringe when hearing this!

In computer science, "code" is used as a [mass noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun), specifying the collection of instructions in a specific arrangement *as a whole* and in no specific quantity. Whether it's one line of code or ten pages, it is still referred to as *code*, not *codes*.

When "codes" is used in computer science, it typically refers to values or constants used to specify a trait, access or properties, though in my experience, the actual name of those types of items is used over the word "codes". For example, instead of:

> Use these codes to specify the read/write permissions of the file.

You would write/say:

> Use these constants to specify the read/write permissions of the file.
>
> *Or:* Use this enumeration to specify the read/write permissions of the file.

---

With regard to the use of "code":

> Use this code to open a file.
>
> Use these functions in the source code to access the database.
>
> This program code needs to be tidied up.

Comment: You used "these codes" in your example, is that correct then ?

Comment: @Shrinath: Only in the sense of security codes, not programming code. [Which is a mass noun.]

Comment: What Orbling said :)

Comment: Where's that quoted definition from? Please do not forget to indicate your sources.

Comment: Code is used like sand: you can have 1, but you cannot say 1 code like you cannot say 1 sand. You can use more words to specify the amount: 1 line of code --> 1 grain of sand.

But like Nick said, you can use codes as a noun, in a container kind of way. When you have access codes, but then you could read that as: I have 3 lines of access code
/

Comment: @Nick Bedford: I'm also a programmer who cringes at "software codes" but "code" is not quite like "fish". `Code` is a `mass noun` like in djerry's example "sand" above. `Mass noun`s refer to `stuff` which cannot be counted and have no plural in certain senses. "Fish" and "sheep" might be called `invariant` since they have a plural but it happens to be identical to the singular. You can say "two fish" but not "two code". But "fish" also has other plural uses and mass noun forms too - "twho fishes", "I ate some fish" (-:

Comment: @djerry: How would you respond to the question "How many codes does the ASCII scheme use for the character 'a'?"

Comment: @oosterwal - one, of course :)

Comment: @oosterwal: that refers to `code` in another acception, which can be pluralized, such as `telegraphic codes`.

Comment: @nico: I agree that it's different than *source code*.  I was merely trying to point out that the way the original question was phrased, "'codes' in a programming context", made it open to a lot of interpretation. Specifically, "in a programming context" does not exclude 'codes' from referring to ASCII, EBCDIC, or unicode character codes, or cryptographic or error correction codes, such as Hamming or Viterbi.

Comment: @oosterwal: point taken :)

Comment: Good point oosterwal. In the context of the given example, yes it wasn't correct, however the word "codes" can, like you said, be used in a programming context to refer to things like ASCII codes ('a' being 97, 'A' being 65).

Comment: For someone wants to use `code` as countable, the word `code snippet(s)` is for you.

Comment: I'm not going to take a stance on whether it's right or wrong, but hearing "codes" will immediately cause a programmer/CS person to doubt that a scientific programming person understands computers (sort of an anti-shibboleth). Just look at all the conflicting answers here.

Answer (score 60):

Yes, it is wrong to use the word "codes" in the programming world if *[source code](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/source_code)* is implied:

> Noun
>
> source code (uncountable)
>
> 1. (computing, **uncountable**) Human-readable instructions in a programming language, to be transformed into machine instructions by a compiler, interpreter, assembler or other such system.

[Uncountable noun](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#uncountable) (my emphasis): "a noun that cannot be used freely with numbers or the indefinite article, and which therefore **takes no plural form**".

The same if *code* refers to a [computer program](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code#Noun):

> (uncountable) A computer program, or more generally, any defined computing process.

In some other contexts it is all right, for example, [access codes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/access_codes).

Comment: To be pedantic, in addition to being incorrect when referring to *source code* it's also incorrect when referring to other types of code, such as *intermediate code* and *machine code*.

Comment: The question asked about "code" not "source code". Why did you add the word "source"? It seems because "source code" says "uncountable" but "code" says "countable or uncountable": https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code#English. Your last quote does not match what the actual website says. I would recommend that you change this answer to reflect the truth that code can be countable or uncountable and remove the part about "source code" or "access code".

Comment: Yes in other contexts it might be correct to use the the term codes.

Answer (score 15):

No, this is not correct when you refer to programming code.

There is no plural when you refer to programming code since when you say code you do mean the whole chunk of it. Even if you say for example "different sets of programming *code*" you notice that no plural is used.

Answer (score 13):

"Codes" is actually correct usage and is quite common in academia and in descriptions of commercial products in fields that utilize numerical methods, such as topology optimization or finite element analysis. It is never used to designate a random program that Joe Coder implemented.

What is really meant by this is "well-known and well-tested libraries that do the job as fast as possible". The complexity of the numerical methods is very high, and since performance and accuracy are critical, the demand on the programming skills of their coders is huge. For this reason, the number of numerical method programming libraries is relatively small, and every self-respecting software product in the field uses one or another.

That being said, I would consider any usage outside this very specific context to be incorrect.

**Update:** By request, some examples below, from different sources:

- [Leading Optimization Codes Integrate into Multiphysics and FEA Environments](https://web.archive.org/web/20110922065655/http://www.comsol.dk/press/news/article/147/) (press release)
- [Application of Flow and Transport Optimization Codes to Groundwater Pump and Treat System Optimization](https://ascelibrary.org/doi/abs/10.1061/40685(2003)84) (conference proceeding)
- [How to Guarantee Finite Termination of Verifying Global Optimization Codes](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1026493608620) (journal paper)
- [A comparison of finite element codes for the solution of biphasic poroelastic problems](http://www.tcd.ie/bioengineering/documents/JEngMed_96_210.PDF) (journal technical note)
- [The usage of standard ﬁnite element codes for computation of dispersion relations in materials with periodic microstructure](http://murphylibrary.uwlax.edu/digital/journals/JASA/JASA1997/PDFS/VOL_102/ISS_4/2007_1.PDF) (journal paper)

Hopefully that's convincing enough. More examples to be had if one searches for "optimization codes", "finite element codes" or similar.

Comment: @Adam: See updated answer for some examples. Usage in document titles is not that common, but in the running text is not unusual, nor is considered an error. I hope this is convincing enough for you.

Comment: @Adam: Also note, the usage of "codes" does not mean "source code" in this case. The "codes" in question are numerical libraries which may be open-source, but may very well be licensed commercially in binary form only. And as I said in my post, any usage besides this very narrow scope is incorrect.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks; that's interesting. Since it's not immediately obvious if the OP is referring to source code, this corner case does seem plausible.

Comment: I'll vouch for this answer. In the scientific programming community, 'codes' is a perfectly acceptable plural to indicate multiple pieces of software that are usually manipulative libraries. @Martin Tapankov is definitely correct, in this narrow context.

Comment: "Codes" is the normal academic usage (at least in BE) to refer to the library(ies), eg smooth particle hydrocodes to model galaxy formation. I imagine the plural is because of all the different calculations involved.

Comment: It's certainly true that some scientific communities use the plural like this.  Whether that community is "correct" to do so is a different matter...

Comment: This accords with my (brief) experience in academia, at a center that used to work almost exclusively on such codes (and then stopped, for a variety of reasons).

Comment: "codes" is largely used by academics in non-computer fields. Whether this is because they have learned it from others such as them or because they are trying to project an image of competence, it is hard to say. I am yet to meet a computer scientist or a professional programmer that refers to the source of their programs as "codes". Users of this fake plural form should be aware that they come across as pretentious and self-important, yet dilettantish.

Comment: @LuboAntonov You may not have met such a person, but they're pretty common in certain subfields. In high-performance computing, "codes" is extremely common.

Comment: it sounds wrong

Comment: Most of the linked sources are no longer available (for whatever reason). At least one of the ones that still is actually uses 'codes' in the context of 'codes and standards', i.e. as in "not up to code", not computer code. Some of the others do appear to do so and I know some scientists that indeed use it like that, but I feel they do so in ignorance of their error, not intentionally. This seems to be birth of a neologism, where mistakes repeated often enough and with sufficient authority, simply become the new way of saying something. I don't think users can point at some solid etymology.

Comment: +1. See the bounty.

Comment: @pboin +1 to your comment. You may be interested in seeing my bounty and all the new answers that have come as a result of it. I'd be happy to see an answer from you too if you're interested. I wouldn't call it a "narrow" context, since "code" is quite frequently used as a synonym of "computer program".

Comment: @cpast Interesting example, since I have studied and worked in HPC and I am yet to meet anybody with a Computer Science degree to use the word "codes". However, there are plenty of physicists and others in that field, and my comment fully applies to them.

Comment: @LuboAntonov I also work in HPC, with computer scientists, and hear "codes" all the time. Including from my professors.

Comment: I have definitely heard and read the term "codes" used in academic contexts. Here, **codes** is understood as **software packages** (a featured implementation of a some algorithm), not the source code.

Answer (score 12):

It is always wrong to use "codes" when refering to a quantity of "source code". Source code is a [mass noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) which should never be pluralised.

There are some however some other cases where it is permissible to use "codes" in a programming context:

- When it is used to describe some form of pre-defined encoding e.g. "HTML status codes 404 and 500 mean page not found and internal server error respectively". Here a code refers to a (singular) element of an encoding so it is fine to pluralise it.
- When used in a security context, e.g. "access codes". Again, an "access code" is singular so it is fine to pluralise it.

Hence "I shall use these codes" may or may not be correct depending on the context.

Comment: Be careful when saying "always".

Answer (score 11):

Generally "code" is a mass noun. At the other end of the spectrum from the "gimme teh codez" crowd, "code" is used as a count noun in some scientific and numerical circles: "I looked at 5 different codes for FFT [Fast Fourier Transform] and didn't like any of them."

Comment: Although *algorithms* would be a more appropriate term in that case.

Comment: Definitely, *codes* is not valid in that example

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone: "valid" means that a group of people use and understand the word to mean that. @nico: No, they use it to mean a program/script/subroutine/function which is an implementation of an algorithm ... could be 5 implementations in 1 to 5 different computer languages of 1 to 5 different algorithms.

Comment: @nico: Code is an implementation of an algorithm.  You can't just substitute one for the other (although the plural word *algorithms* is used more often, thus feeling more natural, it isn't correct).  But code is still uncountable, if you want to introduce count, *implementations* would be best.

Comment: reading your example I immediately thought that you were implying having looked at 5 different ways to perform FFT, so 5 different algorithms. If you want to say that they were written in different languages than, as you say, you should use *5 different implementations* to avoid any confusion. Personally I don't hear using the word *codes* (plural) so much in scientific circles... but there may be regionality in that.

Comment: "Code" and "Codes" are commonly used as John Machin describes. See also Martin Tapankov's answer.

Comment: I think this answer would be improved if you removed the part about the "gimme teh codez" crowd. It is also the scientific computing crowd: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/20490/21450

Comment: Unfortunately the user has not been active on any SE site since 2017.

Comment: "Gimme teh codez" is deliberately incorrect, that's the joke - just look at the middle word!

Comment: Citation needed.

Answer (score 2):

## It can be used both ways, based on intended meaning

The answer to this question is found in the "usage".

OP:

> Is it wrong to use the word "codes" in programming context?

> > I shall use these codes.

It depends on what you are referring to, even in programming context.

If you mean a list of passwords, references (eg 'error codes'), a series of long character strings and formulas for computation, or sub-kernel/sub-C level lines used by compilers or interpreters that Bill Joy might use to make binary talk to the hardware, then no, it is not wrong.

If you mean a section of JavaScript, HTML embed snippets, or even multiple Python files, then yes, it would be wrong from an English usage viewpoint.

In the ESL world, we would say that the word "code" in reference to the many lines of, say, a PHP web app or system process written in C is "[uncountable](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-countable-un.htm)". This echoes a concept in another answer about "mass nouns".

**[English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-countable-un.htm)**:

> uncountable nouns are substances, concepts etc that we cannot divide into separate elements

This does not mean that nouns must always be used as only countable or uncountable. Note, that explanation from English Club does not describe "words" themselves as only being either countable or uncountable, but the "substances, concepts" etc nouns may refer to. Take for example "water"...

**Uncountable**:

> He spilled **water** on the floor.

**Countable**:

> Please bring me **a water**. (a glass of water)

> Minnesota has many **waters**. (bodies of water)

As a coder myself, if I said, "Use these codes," I would be referring to something like what Google provides, discussed in this linked article, which uses "codes" in the plural as part of the title:

**[Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)**:

> **Sign in with backup *codes***

Right away, because "codes" is plural, I know this Google article is not a PHP or Python script; it is a group of passwords.

Personally, I don't often say, "codes," in reference to `exit` codes, though I might; I say, "exit codes," for clarity, largely due to the reasons behind this question.

In the uncountable, "code" is often treated like water, rice, or pasta—they don't have "[noun-number](http://www.english-for-students.com/Noun-Number.html)" (plural/singular). "Code" in reference to the contents of a software application is like a giant bowl of pasta and each "line" is like a noodle. That imagery could serve as a guide.

I suppose one could say...

> Here are the codes you can use on our server.

...in reference to a series of short commands or code snippets, but I think it rather amateur to use the plural countable it that way. And, I might not hire a person simply based on hearing that, whether for teaching English or for a coding job. It would tell me a lot about the quality of English usage the coder would be putting into UX instructions in an app and the lack of exposure the applicant had to experienced people in the industry. But, now I've just crossed into other topics of Workplace and UX.

If I want to use a plural noun to describe "code" in reference outside passwords and encryption keys, I prefer either "commands" or "lines of code" (also known as [LOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code)).

---

*I write partially from my experience, having my own computer course at [github.com/inkverb/vip](https://github.com/inkVerb/VIP/blob/master/README.md) and my own English course with style guides at [write.pink](https://write.pink). This is how I use the word in my work.*

Comment: However "code" in the programming context doesn't only mean "lines of code" it also can have another meaning which is simply a synonym of "computer program" and in that situation it is countable.

Comment: '[T]he word "code" is "uncountable" ' displays a misconception that has often been addressed on ELU. In 'My favourite drink is coffee,' _coffee_ is non-count. However, in 'The two most common coffees are _arabica_ and _robusta_,' and also in 'Two coffees, please,' _coffee_ is count. Saying that a noun is count or non-count (especially when it exhibits both behaviours) is misleading. Noun _usages_ are count or non-count (and even this classification presents problems. _6000 police_ has broadened in acceptability beyond headlinese, but _3 police_ is unacceptable.)

Comment: @NikeDattani, example, pretty please :-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It is about usage, I agree, which was why I addressed both uses. In your wonderful coffee example, I'll expand as someone who walks among coffee trees here in Asia: The long version would be "two most common coffee beans" or "two most common coffee trees", shortening it so that coffee takes the plural. That doesn't correct or change the accuracy of what you wrote, but it does help clarify what is going on as a guide for why one would use coffee, water, or code as non-count or countable. Thanks!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I also made an edit for clarity as per your point and our last name on ELU: "used in this way" Thank you!

Comment: You can look up the process of _countification_, new count usages of nouns appearing and being accepted, in an in-house search. The reverse process is rarer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your explanation of how nouns can be countable in some contexts and uncountable in others, in addition to the statement that saying a noun is "count or non-count is misleading" and that it's ***usages*** that are count or non-count, is exactly the type of answer I was looking for when I posted this bounty. I would gladly give it to you if you want to write an answer. Jesse: there's 5 examples here: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/20490/21450

Comment: @NikeDattani Then I will re-write my answer because my answer demonstrated as much by showing different "uses" of both the plural and the non-count, it just didn't use the word "use" in doing so. After a recent edit, it did. I will look at your examples before I do. Thanks.

Comment: @NikeDattani Thank you both for this. When I demonstrated the countable and uncountable uses of "codes" in my original answer, I didn't consider that it needed to be said that it needed to be said. In the ESL world, I deal with the two count-related uses of a given noun so often, I forget to state directly that it is "usage" I'm explaining. So, I added "usage" to state this directly and also illustrated it with a water example in my answer.

Comment: "we would say that the word 'code' used in this way is..." . . . . What do you mean by "this" way?

Comment: @NikeDattani It was an cataphoric "this" which needs clarity. :-) Editing

Comment: @NikeDattani Edited. Bounty-worthy or not, how is that?

Comment: @Nike Dattani It's all been covered here before. [Count vs mass – where can you look {up which nouns are which}?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94618/count-vs-mass-where-can-you-look-this-up/94628#94628). 'Beware broad-brush approaches, even if you find a dictionary offering the count - uncount classification. Some – perhaps many – nouns are non-count in some senses and count in others. Coffee is a good example – its basic sense is uncount ...'.

Comment: ... You may also find the discussion at ['sufferings' is plural, though it is uncountable ... but _how_?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174610/sufferings-is-plural-though-it-is-uncountable-but-how/174618#174618) useful. One has to consider for each **usage** (appearance in a sentence) of a noun (1) morphological form // (2) countness (can you insert 1, 6, 23 ... here, with necessary adjustment to the verb form?) // (3) verb agreement // (4) etic countability ('furniture': usually multiple items ... chairs, tables ...).

Comment: I appreciate the knowledge of these comments and hope they stay here for reference. But, I must share that when to use countable and non-counts for me is never a problem because I've worked in ESL for over a decade and I write so often that, for me, I don't need to think about it anymore. Maybe I should be humble and describe my thinking a little more, even though it seems so obvious to me. This has shown me how difficult it really can be for people who have put their diligence into other topics and the value ELU has to offer people.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sounds like you can write a good answer here. I need to give the bounty to at least one person.

Comment: @Nike Dattani Isn't there a way to cancel it? If the question reduces to the concepts I've mentioned above, it has an answer on another thread and should be closed. Keeping the site easily searchable and free of bloat, rather than reputation hikes, are important.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No there is no way to cancel a bounty, and even if there was I wouldn't want to. If you think it "should" have been closed, you can vote to lose it, but I predict that 0 people will join you, whereas you need 4 other people to agree with your close vote for the question to actually close. After this comment https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2186/can-i-use-two-different-codes/2189#comment4038_2186 I searched for evidence to show the user that "codes" can be used as a countable noun, and this page came up. Not the other two. Please help make this site searchable!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would rather say that the _sense_ is countable or uncountable, not the usage.  The most common context in which _coffee_ (and most food words) is countable is when it means "cup of coffee" (or "serving of [whatever]"), as in "I'll have three coffees and six bagels, please."

Comment: @phoog I wouldn't. The anchor involved when the captain gives the command "Weigh anchor" is the same sense as that in "We've lost another anchor! That makes three anchors we've lost in the reefs at various times,, and it's always a dangerous event when your ship only carries one."

Answer (score 2):

Computer "code" is called that because it consists of a sequence of "opcodes" (operation codes) which specify the actions for the computer to take.  Some place early in the evolution of computer jargon an instance of such a sequence came to be called "code", for no well-defined reason -- this is just the way that jargon develops.

But "codes" still exist in computing.  In addition to the opcodes, one might speak of the code sequences for the individual sin, cosine, and tangent functions as "codes for the trig functions" -- it's just a matter of what jargon fits the current needs.

And, of course, there are error codes, status codes, codes used in documentation, etc.

And it needs to be noted that while (to the uninitiated) most of these codes are cryptic, they do not involve encryption per se -- totally unrelated from "code" in the cryptographic sense.

Comment: +1. This is my favorite answer so far since posting the bounty. It doesn't even touch on my own peeve with the top-voted answers, which is that "code" is a countable noun when used as a synonym of computer program, for example when talking about the codes GAUSSIAN and MOLPRO. However it introduces us to the history of where the word "code" originated and provides so much more insight such as the existence of other types of codes like error correcting codes and such. Great answer all around.

Answer (score 1):

As Macmillan Dictionary notes, *[code](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/code_1)* as used in a software context is *either* countable or uncountable:

> **code** COUNTABLE/UNCOUNTABLE ​COMPUTING a set of instructions that a computer
> can understand

Ngrams shows that *computer code* is currently used about four times more frequently than *computer codes*:

[image: computer code vs computer codes]

The [*Corpus of Contemporary American English*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) shows the same pattern -- *computer code* appears in the literature about four times more frequently than *computer codes*.

However, while another answer asserts that the phrase *computer codes* is restricted mainly to describe software written for numerical computing, COCA shows about the same distribution of of its use in both mainstream and scientific literature as *computer code*.

Usage is not definition; while *computer code* is used more frequently, especially in American English, *computer codes* is a perfectly valid term for describing a body of software and firmware.

Answer (score 0):

Is it wrong to use the word "codes" in programming context?

```
I shall use these codes.
```

Actually you can say "1 code " but in a different context. This might be a letter substitution code or a rotating modular code just to mention a few. These are not considered in the current discussion which is a larger problem.

I am with Nick Bedford above in cringing at a computer program's content being referred to as code. Code is meant to purposely hide or obscure the information given. That is characteristic of only the *Worst* program content. A mistake here is that in rushing to illustrate this opinion we miss (partly) what the original question represents. Any other question like this would demand more context. Here we discuss opinions about the mass noun versus the individual but over look the vagueness of the original question.

My answer to the question would be the same as Nick Bedford's. I did not wish to detract from it, only add some more detail that did not fit in a comment.

Comment: The question is vague, because if you're talking about "lines of code" the word "code" is uncountable but if you're talking about the codes GAUSSIAN and MOLPRO then it is countable. You are right that people were mistaken by rushing to illustrate their opinion on a question that was extremely vague. I can't give you an upvote though because I can't figure out what your answer is to the question of whether or not it's okay to use the word "codes" in a programming context. My bounty is particularly aimed at going to an answer that gives the perspective that "codes" can be okay in some contexts.