# Count vs. mass — where can you look this up?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, resources

Most dictionaries don't say whether a noun is [count vs. mass](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/massnouns/).  Short of asking a fluent English speaker, where can you get this kind of information?

I've tried asking various other ESL/EFL people I know this same question, and also tried googling it, but to no avail.

Comment: As a request for resources, belongs on ELU.Meta.

Comment: This is too old to migrate to meta, but perhaps the powers that be could make it happen. @Laurel is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most English dictionaries used and published in the United States don't include that information, just as they don't provide [IPA-based phonemic transcription](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf). However, dictionaries published in the UK and elsewhere sometimes do, especially dictionaries for English learners.

One American online exception is [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/), which dutifully reports that *pea* and *bean* are both `[count]`, while *rice* and *sand* are both `[noncount]`.

Comment: "sands" in Google Books: "About 15,400,000 results" incl. *Sands, powders, and grains: an introduction to the physics of granular materials*; *Dynamics of marine sands: a manual for practical applications*; and of course, "shifting sands" *Shifting Sands: A Guidebook for Crossing the Deserts of Change*;

Comment: This is a result of the well-established countification process for mass nouns. Why waste a perfectly good plural suffix when it can be used to signal something else, like diversity of type (_15 inks used in this drawing_) or vastness of extent (_sands of the Sahara_)? There is also a massification for count nouns, referring to undifferentiated physical or spiritual phenomena (_a lot of car for the money_), etc.

Answer (score 12):

Beware broad-brush approaches, even if you find a dictionary offering the count – uncount classification. Some – perhaps many – nouns are non-count in some senses and count in others. Coffee is a good example – its basic sense is uncount:

> Coffee is a drink made by infusing the ground beans of Coffea arabica
> etc.
>
> Too much coffee can be bad for you.

However, different products will be count:

> Coffees produced using a higher proportion of robusta beans in the
> blend tend to be bitter and have less flavour but better body than
> those with a higher proportion of arabica beans.

And ellipsis produces another count-noun polyseme:

> Two coffees, please.
>
> (ie two cups / mugs of coffee)

*Rice* is count when different strains are meant, and *sand* when different sorts are being mentioned. (There is a poetic use of *sands* also.) Even *furnitures* is allowed in certain situations.

There are also grey areas – you'd probably ask for less peas rather than fewer peas (especially if they were mushy) on your plate. Non-count doesn't always mean that counting would be impossible - confetti is treated as a singular non-count noun. The difficulty ensuing when one tries to use *algae* in both count and non-count senses has recently been addressed in a different thread.

A good place to start looking is http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/nouns/common-problems-countuncount-nouns .

Comment: Note that I'm not asking for general approaches to distinguishing the two (I'm a native English speaker), but looking for a reference that learners can use.

Comment: The Collins Cobuild English Dictionary for Advanced Learners (certainly my copy - Edition 3, 2001) differentiates nouns as you require. It also tries to parse common phrases. It uses the term 'mass noun' for 'nouns which are normally uncount, but [behave in count fashion] when varieties are being referenced' - such as _wine_ in I like wine / I like French wines.

Comment: I don't think I've heard countable rice, but it should follow spice. "In a Japanese supermarket, you can find numerous rices."

Comment: If you can find a general set of rules, then learners can use that, instead of relying on a reference. There is a general semantic principle at play; I don't think this is a case of English speakers memorizing numerous exceptions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, your *comment* is a great answer to my question.

Comment: +1 A landmark answer that makes this post stand out on ELU and by the way earns the OP an up vote as well for having initiated the post.

Answer (score 4):

You should try [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/). It lists the plural, or indicates that the noun is uncountable. For example, [rice](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rice) is listed as uncountable, and [bean](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bean) has the plural listed as beans.

Comment: After five beers, beer looks uncountable. Oops! And it can be made from lots of barleys, not just one variety of barley, just like sake can be made from various rices.

Comment: @Kaz, true, but I call shenanigans.

Comment: I don't know if Wiktionary has changed since this answer was posted, but rice is described as "countable and uncountable" and barley as "usually uncountable". Nonetheless, it's reasonable to headline the far more common uncountable sense, as pretty much any English word can be pluralised, even adjectives and adverbs and conjunctions (*ifs* and *buts* and *maybes* are well known but you can do it with others).

Answer (score 0):

wikiontary and etymologyonline.com are good sources.

Mass / COME / COMMITTER Nouns are Continuum-like descriptions for features that are integrated / unified / committed to making up the object (usually because they are continuous or undifferentiated)

COUNTER Nouns are Discrete-like descriptions for features that are separately making up the object

Comment: I don't see any mention of countness at etymologyonline.com, and Wiktionary has already been mentioned.