# Grammar: "This changes state that has this property"

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, zero-article

I came across this sentence in *The Rust Programming Language*:

> : calling the 'next' method on an iterator changes internal state that the iterator uses to keep track of where it is in the sequence.

It seems to me like the state needs an article in the main clause. On the other hand

> I'm drinking a water that isn't sparkly.

sounds fine to me, even with the article omitted. Am I wrong in thinking the former case is grammatically incorrect?
If not, what differentiates the two cases?

Comment: ? *the method changes state that the iterator uses*... I think you are right.

Comment: It seems you can use *state* as a noncount noun with *change* when *change* is acting ergatively; that is, when something changes state, it does it to itself. A method can change state (change its state).  A method can change *the* state of something else. But it can’t “change state” of something else. You need the article. And “calling a method” can’t change state at all (but it can change a state).

Comment: If something isn't a sentence, then typically it's meaningless to debate whether it's grammatical. Your quote doesn't seem to be a sentence, because it doesn't start with a capital letter. It feels like note or bulletted list format, in which articles, auxiliaries, and other minor words are often omitted.

Answer (score 3):

The first example is, in fact, correct.

In computing, the word "state" can be used as a noncount noun. As the paper ["The Importance of Students’ Attention to Program State: A Case Study of Debugging Behavior"](http://blogs.hmc.edu/lewis/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/07/Lewis2012_Debugging.pdf) explains:

> State represents the idea, present in all programming environments, of a set of temporary or permanent variables that completely describe the current environment on which a program can act. This includes programmer-defined variables as well as other aspects of the runtime environment such as the current stack frame. Program commands change aspects of the computer program’s state and the process of writing programs involves developing sequences of state change operations to achieve a particular goal.

In this case, "internal state that the iterator uses" refers more specifically to the data in some set of mutable fields within the iterator.

Comment: And 'a water' might be construed as either non-count (from [[a blinding light / a blinding sunlight?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227855/a-blinding-light-blinding-sunlight-a-blinding-sunlight)}: These nouns fail the 'no a/an' test for massness but pass the 'no numerals' test. Thus 'The state gave me a good education' but not ' ...  two good educations'. 'I have an understanding of the principles involved' but not 'I have two understandings ...'. 'I felt a strange warmth' but not 'They felt two strange warmths'. ... or a countified usage (2 spring waters that I recommend ...).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "A water" can also be used to mean "a glass/serving of water," thus making it an ordinary count noun; see [this ELL answer.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/222770/167104) You mostly see this in restaurant orders ("We'd like two waters"); I'm not sure if this is AmE-specific.

Comment: Predated by [count vs mass ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94618/count-vs-mass-where-can-you-look-this-up/94628#94628) and [Can i use the word milks {noun}?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111357/can-i-use-the-word-milks-when-discussing-kinds-of-milk/111364#111364).

Comment: The noncount reading of "internal state" seem very forced to me. (I think it's because of the restrictive relative clause, but perhaps Tinfoil Hat is onto something, too.) If not explicitly ungrammatical, it's certainly something that I would have recommended the writer avoid.

Comment: How does that explain the *the method changes state that the iterator uses*? I call typo. [Here](https://blog.knoldus.com/iterator-producing-iterator-in-rust-is-really-helpful/) you can find the same piece of Rust code referred to in the OP’s example along with a description using an article in front *internal state*: *The `num_iter` is made mutable because the `next` method used in the next few statements changes **the** internal state of the iterator.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat There's no authoritative source on tech jargon, of course, but to me it sounds equally good with or without the article. "X changes internal state that the iterator uses" means: "there is some state, which is internal to the iterator and used by it, that X changes."

Comment: But you just said *there is some state* —  not *there is state*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat "Some" can be used with noncount nouns; that's the sense I was using here.

Comment: OK, well, I won’t carry on in comments, but that’s like comparing *I’ll take some water* with *I’ll take some state*.