# Can "apple" be a uncountable noun?

Tags: grammar, nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, quantifiers

teachers
which one is correct in the following phrases?

1. a **piece** of apple
2. a **piece** of apple**s**
3. a **part** of **an** apple
4. a **part** of apple

Besides, I saw *apple* is defined as N-VAR in Collins Dictionary.
And one sentence given is:

> His ongoing search for the finest varieties of **apple**.

Can I use *apples* here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it can be uncountable. *I prefer apple and blackberry in my fruit pies*.

Comment: Yes. *This fruit spread tastes mostly of apple.*

Comment: In addition, 1 is correct, 2 isn't. 3 is also correct (4 isn't), but has a different meaning. The stalk or pips could be "part of an apple", but if you were offering someone something to eat, you would offer them a "piece of apple".

Comment: It's uncountable when speaking of apple flesh, or cooked apple, as a substance.   'Varieties of apple' means varieties of that particular species of tree, so the singular is correct.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/122321/191178

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks so much for your kind help!!! That means "two pieces of apple" it is still a countable noun? But can I say "varieties of apples?"

Comment: Related: [“I like apples” vs “I like apple”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/365808)