# Not specifying the amount that you eat/drink

Tags: indefinite-articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, food

You don't need to specify the amount that you eat/drink for some things:

> I drink cranberry juice.
>
> I eat fried chicken.
>
> I eat bread with butter.

You can't do this for other things:

> I eat cheeseburger. (Wrong)

You need to specify the amount of cheeseburger(s) that you eat.

> I eat a cheeseburger. (One)
>
> I eat cheeseburgers. (More than one)
>
> I eat half of a cheeseburger. (Specific amount less than a whole)

How can you not specify the amount of food/drink(s) that you consume for stuff like burgers for which the root form is invalid in this case?

Comment: Non-specific would be *cheeseburgers*.

Comment: @Robusto What if you want to be so vague that you can even eat fractional amounts of cheeseburger(s)?

Comment: Related: [“I like apples” vs “I like apple”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/365808/i-like-apples-vs-i-like-apple?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Your question is not a duplicate of: [When to use “the” before food names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58067/when-to-use-the-before-food-names) but the answers explain why and how to use the indefinite article (a/an).

Comment: @sag: If you want to be intentionally vague about fractional amounts you will need another locution, such as "I may have taken a bite or two of a cheeseburger now and then."

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The last sentence

Comment: Thanks, sag, and please be a lot more realistic. Which "last sentence" are you talking about, please?

Surely not "How to not specify the amount of food/drink(s) that you consume for stuff like burgers for which the root form is invalid in this case?" which was your actual last sentence.

Did you mean "I eat half of a cheeseburger. (Specific amount less than a whole)'?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin "How to not specify the amount of food/drink(s) that you consume for stuff like burgers for which the root form is invalid in this case?" is the question.

Comment: Jolly good, sag. Why not either explain what you meant by "The last sentence" or transpose your Question into useful English or preferably, both?

Either way, please note "How to not specify the amount of food/drink(s) that you consume for stuff like burgers for which the root form is invalid in this case" will never work in English.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I'm not saying he wouldn't be better off [at ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com) but it's worth noting that, in China and several other countries, the ESL programs make an absolute hash of the distinction between the question form "how do you ~" and the noun form "how to ~" because their native language's grammar doesn't make a similar distinction. It's better to help OP rephrase (done) than to just complain that you don't see any possible intended question, which wasn't really the case.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin might be time you catch up on CoC https://stackoverflow.com/conduct there's a sense patronization in your frequent use of "please" that's become almost a trademark.

Comment: What is the context for your sentence? Are you talking about 1) a specific time when you eat some unspecified amount of one or more cheeseburgers, or 2) the general fact that cheeseburgers are among the foods that you regularly eat, in different amounts at different times? They're pretty much the same for non-count nouns, but with count nouns like cheeseburger the general statement is much easier than the ambiguous specific instance.

Comment: @JoshG is your edit based on this comment by the OP: *What if you want to be so vague that you can even eat fractional amounts of cheeseburger(s)*? I would suggest that copying that comment would be less invasive than the edit you proposed and which was (mistakenly) approved by two experienced users.

Comment: @Mari-LouA someone, at some point in this thread said they didn't understand the OP's question. I didn't like the idea of directly editing the question because that truly is putting words in someone's mouth, so I opted for brackets so that someone could see that this was my interpretation of the question.

Comment: @JoshG I've refrained from responding because I was hoping someone else would in my place. But your interpretation of what the OP is asking is exactly that. It's your personal interpretation. Your username is not included in the edit, "I think the OP"  which means if anyone else edits the question, the author of the clarification will be unknown unless someone looks at the edit history.

Comment: @sag Do you agree with JoshG's interpretation? Please edit your post and remove the brackets and  the reference "I think the OP"

Comment: @Mari-LouA how is editing the question directly, without noting in it "I think" any better? At that point you've put your own interpretation into the edit but haven't alerted people to the fact that you've edited it with your interpretation. With my method, I've allowed readers to decide if my interpretation is correct or not, vs the conventional way which dupes the reader into thinking that the question said that all along. I'm puzzled as to why you think the conventional method is better.

Comment: @JoshG I've added your name to the edit, and separated your interpretation of the question from the original post.

Comment: @Mari-LouA if you're going to make such a fuss about this, feel free to just remove my edit. This is getting to be ridiculous; I'm spending too much time hearing from you about this very minor matter.

Comment: @JoshG As you suggested, I removed your edit. We can't allow inline commentary on *any* question (or answer). That is no better than everybody posting all of their comments within the question itself. Everybody could post their own "this is what I think was meant"—and that would quickly devolve into incomprehensibility. Editing of questions and answers is not meant for this. Commentary should be reserved for comments; interpretation for individual answers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Really? Might be time for you to catch up on common sense or basic language, if not both… or justify your opinion?.

Comment: @Ily Could it be worth noting that in other countries, ESL programs make a hash only if you believed ELL could change that, or it changed the structure of English?

I suggest it's better to help OP rephrase something to fit English, than to mention any other language.

I think it ludicrously unlikely that any sophisticated language such as Chinese can’t make the distinctions you deny.

If you believeany other half-way modern language can’t distinguish I eat a cheeseburger, I eat cheeseburgers and I eat half of a cheeseburger, can you explain in pure translation what that language uses?

Comment: Sorry, Sag; you’re simply mistaken.
We very clearly can and do use “I eat cheeseburger” in exactly the same way you suggest “I drink cranberry juice” or “eat fried chicken/bread with butter”. If you doubt that, please explain.
You need to specify the amount of cheeseburger or cranberry juice, fried chicken, bread with butter or whatever only if you’re talking about “when” or “how often” you eat it. Otherwise, it’s like stating you’re vegetarian or vegan… it is. How could it matter when, where or why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't going to be a way of phrasing this in an expected way that fulfills what you're looking for. However, I believe I have an unexpected way of phrasing this that *will* serve the purpose.

When using the noun, it's either singular or plural.

Fractions can be taken into account in this way:

> I sample a cheeseburger.
>   I sample some cheeseburgers.

But even though the actual *amount* eaten is now unknown, the sample size must still be specified as a singular or plural.

This is closer to what you're looking for, but not close enough.

---

The only way I can think of to truly accommodate an unknown amount eaten and  an unknown sample size is by not using *cheeseburger* as a noun but as an adjective:

> I engage in cheeseburger eating.

Adjectives are commonly used in singular form, even when referring to a plural number of objects. Therefore, the fact that it's *cheeseburger* here does not restrict the sample size to a single cheeseburger.

Not only do we not know how many cheeseburgers are involved in the process, we also don't know how many (in whole or part) are actually being consumed.

Comment: Jason, are you sure it's not "I engage in cheesburgerial eating"? :-)

Comment: This is indeed an ingenious answer to the specific question posed by the OP (assuming JoshG's interpretation of the question is correct), but for the benefit of those who may be browsing this site with the aim of improving their English, it may be worthwhile to add that most people would look with considerable puzzlement at somebody who, in the course of everyday communication, spoke of engaging in cheeseburger eating.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, of course. The *short* answer is that there's no way of saying it in a completely natural way that has the desired effect. This was the best I could come up with. :)

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to notice about this question is that it really isn't about quantifying objects. The second thing is that it's not about the verbs *eat* and *drink*. Instead, judging from the example sentences, it's about the generic use of verbs.

Notice that every example sentence is in the present tense, and involves an active verb. That makes it generic; i.e, it's not describing the present time (that's what the present progressive is for), and it's not describing the past or the future, except by implication -- instead, it's describing **generic**, habitual behavior. Generic use of an active predicate essentially converts it into a stative predicate referring to repeated (if possible, identical) events.

That changes all sorts of things, like the fact that if I say *I eat meat*, for instance, I may eat 10 grams at one time and 100 grams at a different time, without affecting the truth of the statement *I eat meat*. I may eat half a cheeseburger, or three at one meal, ditto.

And this is true not just of eating and drinking (though it's true we **do** talk generically a lot about eating and drinking -- the sense of these verbs used generically is to comment on personal or social tolerance of various food and drink).

If you say *I eat yogurt* you're indicating at least that you tolerate it. You're not really summing up all your yogurt for quantification. 
This lack of quantificational rigor is true of practically any transitive active verb used generically:

- *She knits sweaters for cats*. (how many sweaters, how many cats? Who knows? Who cares?)
- *He reads science fiction.* (A singular mass noun object)
- *He reads a lot of science fiction.* (quantified = *He reads science fiction a lot*)
- *He reads science fiction novels.* (a plural count noun object; plural because repeated)
- *He reads a lot of science fiction novels.* (quantified = *He reads science fiction novels a lot.*)

I could go on at some length. Fortunately, however, I already did, and for more than anyone sane could possibly want to know about English generics, see [*Studies in English Generics*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/dissertation/).

Comment: In the comments on this question, **1006a** points out that there are two possible ways of interpreting it. This answer assumes the second of the two interpretations. Unfortunately, the OP has never responded to **1006a**'s comment, so there is no way of knowing which of the two was intended.

Comment: There is a context in which _I eat fried chicken_ can simply refer to one event of eating, and that's when a series of actions is being listed in the present tense for a narrative: _I get up in the morning, I go to work, I eat a sandwich for lunch, I go home, I eat fried chicken for supper, I watch TV, I go to bed._

Comment: Although all of the examples that appear in the question are in the present tense, it is not clear whether the tense is essential to the question. Suppose that I want to convey, in the past tense, that yesterday I had some cheeseburger-stuff for dinner, but I want to leave it unspecified whether that was two-thirds of a cheeseburger, or one, or one and a half, or two, etc. The OP's question *could* be (but doesn't have to be) interpreted to cover such cases as well.

Answer (score 2):

> How [can you] not specify the amount of food/drink(s) that you consume for stuff like burgers...?

## By saying “cheeseburgers.”

The things that don't require articles are **uncountable**, either naturally (water) or because you're talking about the substance (beef) *as* a substance and not as a specific instance. “I eat fried chicken” is talking about the *substance* ‘fried chicken’ and not about specific *pieces* of fried chicken.

There is no ‘cheeseburger substance’ (it's called ‘beef’ or ‘hamburger’) so you **must** use an article.

However, saying “I eat cheeseburgers” doesn't *necessary* imply that you have ever actually eaten any particular number of cheeseburgers in your life. It's just the way of speaking vaguely that it's something that's acceptable for dinner.

If you really *needed* to underline that you're speaking hypothetically, you'd change the **verb**: “I could eat a cheeseburger” (right now, for this meal) or “I could eat cheeseburgers” (generally, whenever) would both get that idea across.

**Edit**: Per your comments, “I could eat some fractional amount of a cheeseburger but not possibly a complete cheeseburger” is not an idea actual humans ever need to express (in any language) so there's no easier way to get that idea across that saying it all explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 different things going here, both are hidden implied subjects under discussion.

The subject will be made clear by the rest of the context of your communication and|or the modifiers you choose for certain words.

Your readers|audience must determine whether the implied subject is a SPECIFIC INSTANCE of an EVENT, or the implied subject describes what happens when the behavior or pattern takes place generally (what's the typical pattern that occurs?).

Specific Event Instance:

```
"I ate half of a cheesburger."
```

General Pattern:

```
"I eat half of a cheeseburger."  
(This is a correct but rare way to get your meaning across because your reader has to 
notice the tiny difference between "ate" and "eat".)  Be kinder to your reader: include 
more signals that the implied subject is "General Pattern".  

"I ONLY eat half of a cheeseburger AT A TIME."
```

A Specific Event Instance could take place in the past, present or future.  The amount (and thus the plural or singular form of the object) needs to agree with the specific amount you discuss for that particular, individual, actual event:

```
"You ate 3 cheeseburgers for breakfast" == "You ate half of a cheeseburger for breakfast."
"You are eating 3 cheeseburgers for lunch" == "You are eating half of a cheeseburger for lunch."
"You will eat 3 cheeseburgers for dinner" == "You will eat half of a cheeseburger for dinner."
```

But the General Pattern (discussing the general pattern all events usually follow) uses the infinitive form of the verb, AND the singular or plural that matches the form of the CATEGORY that the object word belongs to:

```
"I eat cheeseburgers." == An individual cheeseburger is an instance of "cheesburgers", 
so we use the category.
"I drive trucks." == An individual truck falls within the "trucks" category.

"I eat bread with butter." == An individual LOAF of bread belongs to the "BREAD" category 
of food.
```

So first you have to identify whether the Subject is [Specific Event Instance] or [General Template For This Behavior-Occurrence Pattern], and then IF it is General Pattern, is the object's CATEGORY plural or singular?

Comment: It is unclear whether this is really an *answer* to the question, or effectively an elaborate comment, pointing out that the question is ambiguous, which has already been noted by 1006a.

Comment: That is not correct.  I have informed the Original Poster that specifying the category for the General Pattern is why no specific amount is needed.  One should not post useful answers as though they were merely comments.  I invite you to stop griefing me, forever, jsw29.