# The definite article 'The' is necessary for the following bold lines?

Tags: definite-articles

Maehara et al, 2011 conducted a research on isolated endophytic fungi/sp from **the quinine bark.**

What is the specific reason if I have to omit 'the' in this context?

Comment: @tchrist Research on micro-organism.

Comment: @des: What tchrist meant was that _research_ is a mass noun in English, and therefore _a research_ is ungrammatical. It has to be quantified like a mass noun.

Comment: @JohnLawler So what can we say instead of "a" research? It is my problem too. I have used it a lot!

Comment: @PersianCat Same as you do with any English mass noun, e.g. *water*. You wouldn't say "*a* water" (except in very special circumstances); you would say "*the* water" if referring to a specific body/sample of water; otherwise you would just say "*water*". In this case you would just say "X conducted *research*"; but when referring to a specific research project, you would say "*the research* which X conducted on Y".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited to [ell.se]

Comment: The phrase _do a research_ seems to have been widely adopted as an idiom in several Asian Englishes. I've heard academics from India, Singapore, Malaysia, Indonesia, China, and Japan all use it. It sounds odd to American ears, however. Dunno about Oz, S.Africa, or elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnLawler Completely agree! Please add Iranians too!.. :)( ..

Comment: @JohnLawler Indeed.  Pleased to know that a native speaker concerns about this "Language+Culture" problem.  The same barrier (probably) occurs when you learn our native languages. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was surprised at your first comment. *(to) do a research* is very common, esp., in conversational English, to mean *(to) do a research project* but not necessarily a formal project. (Now, don't do a research, just take my word for it.) It's not common in the US, and that's a different matter.

Comment: LOL.... I hope I won't read a debate amongst the native speakers over this case.

Answer (score 1):

"The" refers to a specific instance or sample of quinine bark.  If you were in the lab and saw a pile of quinine bark you might say to a colleague "I'm going to run a test on the quinine bark," but to the rest of the world there is just quinine bark in general, which is (presumably) what the research hinges on.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @TrevorD that this is more suited to [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Your sentence should be rewritten as follows:

> Maehara et al. (2011) conducted research on endophytic fungi sp. isolated from
>   quinine bark.

As @TrevorD explained, "research" and "bark" are [mass nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94618/count-vs-mass-where-can-you-look-this-up). So, in the context of your sentence, they do not need articles.

I also moved "isolated" to indicate that the fungi was separated from the bark and imply that the separation was performed as part of the research. If you say, "isolated fungi sp.," it implies that isolation is a property of the fungi.